# SQL Query With Conditional Formulas and Grouping

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, grouping

I have a table in our ERP that contains Routing for products that we manufacture (it is called Routing). Each product has unique routing steps that have information such has setup time and cycle time required to complete a single unit.  What I need to do is return a table grouped by part number that displays the total cycle hours for a given part number.  If the units in the table were already in hours this would not be an issue.  Unfortunately/fortunately our ERP allows for cycle times to be specified in a number of different units.  Of course this unit is available in the table but I am struggling with writing a query that will first convert from (in most cases) parts per hour to hours per part, then sum the result for each routing step and return the data grouped by part number.  I am having trouble formatting a table and my reputation is not high enough to add an image so I am not able to show how the data looks.

Here is the formula I use in PowerPivot to convert to hours.

=IF([CycleUnit] = "P" ,1.0/[CycleTime],   IF ([CycleUnit] = "M",[CycleTime]/60.0,   IF([CycleUnit]="H",[CycleTime],BLANK() )))

I am new to SQL and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add your databse tag

Comment: What database system is your back end?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, knowing your database system would be helpful.

What about something like this:

```
select sum( case cycleUnit
            when 'P' then 1.0/cycleTime
            when 'M' then cycleTime/60.0
            when 'H' then cycleTime
            end
            ) as cycleHours
from Routing
group by partNumber
```

The case statement handles your conversions.  Alternatively, you could try making a scalar function that takes in the cycleTime and unit as parameters and returns the converted value.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward time for a case statement

```
select 
 part_no,
 sum(case cycle_unit
   when 'P' then 1.0/cycle_time
   when 'M' then cycle_time/60
   when 'H' then cycle_time
 end) as work_hours      
from routing
group by part_no;
```